# Type error returning an interface for grpc tls credentials

Tags: go, ssl, grpc

I am writing some code that generates grpc tls credentials for multiple services, therefore I want to write it in a modular way so that it can accept certificates through various means. Although I feel like the code has become spaghetti and confusing.

My aim was for the `GetCredentials()` and `GetTls()` methods to be able to be called and configured from different places in order to generate credentials for multiple services.

The problem that I am having atm is in the `GetCfgCredentials()` and `GetCfgTls()`, I want them to return the interface but I get a type error

```
Cannot use 'credentials' (type credentials.TransportCredentials) as the type CfgCredentials Type does not implement 'CfgCredentials' as some methods are missing: GetCredentials() *credentials.TransportCredentials
```

Can anyone with experience tell me what they think of the way I've structured the code I listed below and of the error? I'm quite new to this and would appreciate some pointers on how to create this in the most modular and flexible way possible.

```
var globalCreds credentials.TransportCredentials

var globalTlsConfig *tls.Config

type CfgCredentialsProvider interface {
    GetCredentials() *credentials.TransportCredentials
}

type CfgTlsProvider interface {
    GetTlsConfig() *tls.Config
}

type CfgCredentials interface {
    CfgCredentialsProvider
}

type CfgTls interface {
    CfgTlsProvider
}

func GetGlobalCreds() (credentials.TransportCredentials, error) {
    if globalCreds == nil {
        creds := credentials.NewTLS(globalTlsConfig)
        globalCreds = creds
    }
    return globalCreds, nil
}

func GetGlobalTls(CertificatePath, PrivateEnhancedMailPath string) (*tls.Config, error) {
    serverCert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(CertificatePath, PrivateEnhancedMailPath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if globalTlsConfig == nil {
        tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{serverCert},
        }
        globalTlsConfig = tlsConfig
    }
    return globalTlsConfig, nil
}

func GetCfgCredentials() (CfgCredentials, bool) {
    credentials, err := GetGlobalCreds()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false
    }
    return credentials, true
}

func GetCfgTls(CertificatePath, PrivateEnhancedMailPath string) (CfgTls, bool) {
    tls, err := GetGlobalTls(CertificatePath, PrivateEnhancedMailPath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, false
    }
    return tls, true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error you are seeing:
`Cannot use 'credentials' (type credentials.TransportCredentials) as the type CfgCredentials Type does not implement 'CfgCredentials' as some methods are missing: GetCredentials() *credentials.TransportCredentials` is because your type does not implement the interface.

It needs to implement the [TransportCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.38.0/credentials#TransportCredentials) interface.